# How should I go about creating a slim version of my web app that does not display photos inline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My (travel related) web app has a lot of photos and many of my Users (but not all) are going to have very slow internet connections. I want to give users the option, for example, to access my web app from https://slim.example.com and in this version, photos will be replaced by a link that says "Click to view Photos - Niagra Falls" and they will open the photos directly from my s3 photobucket as opposed to having those photos inline and I would also want to not display certain ads that might be slow to load and maybe instead of paginating 20 objects, I would only paginate 10 objects, etc.

Can you please give me an idea of how I can go about doing this?

The app is interactive. The users will be creating content, etc. So if I create two separate web apps they will need to communicate with each other and rely on the same models/databases.

EDIT:

```
def slim_mode 
  if request.subdomain == 'slim' 
    @slim == true 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ApplicationController` in a before_action you can determine whether the user in a slim mode (by using `request.subdomain`) and save it in an instance variable.

You can also define a helper method in `ApplicationController` which has access to this instance variable and conditionally delegates to image_tag helper or link_to helper.

Comment: is the code that i edited into the question above what you had in mind?

Comment: Along with that we can define a helper `slim_image_tag` which will check `@slim` and call either `image_tag` or `link_to`, this will avoid having to check for `@slim` all over your codebase.